# Vtiger Customer Portal setup issue

Tags: php, vtiger

This is stupid but I cant understand what is wrong. I am trying to setup [Vtiger Customer Portal](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/vtigercrm/vtiger_Customer_Portal_4_2.zip?download)

I followed the [User Guide](https://wiki.vtiger.com/archives/index.php/Vtiger_Customer_Portal_User_Guide#Installing_vtiger_Customer_Portal)

but when I try to access the index page of `customerportal` Nothing appears on the screen as if nothing is written in the index.php file. in firebug it shows an error:
`The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

but this should not be the reason for a program not working. right ? how can i start debugging what is wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

do you still have the problem? Did you make sure that you put the URL of the customer portal in the config.inc.php of the actual vTiger installation?

e.g

```
$PORTAL_URL = 'http://mysite.co.uk/portal';
```